# How to skip hidden rows while iterating through Google Spreadsheet w/ Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps, google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a Google Spreadsheet with many hidden rows in it, and I want to skip them when iterating through a list of rows in the spreadsheet.

It's mainly an efficiency issue, as I'm dealing with over half of my rows being hidden and in no need of being checked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Good question.  The api has functions for hiding and showing rows, but seems to have nothing for querying the show/hide status. Seems like a reasonable enhancement request.

Comment: Yup - this one annoys me too.  Would love to have a solution

Comment: The only lead I have is that when you make a named range that spans a column, if you query the number of rows in that range, you get the number of non-hidden rows. Yet, it still iterates through ALL the rows. Not only is this strange, but it also breaks code that iterates through "all rows" of a named range...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no direct way of doing this in Apps Script, but there is a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=195) open to provide a way get the show/hide status of a row, if you want to star it.

Comment: That request has been open for three years, now. Today, with 89 stars, it's the oldest request for Sheets api functionality in the top 10.

Comment: No more. See Gravity Grave answer below.

Answer (score 9):

New API as of 2018 that's useful for this problem: [isRowHiddenByUser](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#isrowhiddenbyuserrowposition). See also `isRowFilteredByUser`.

Comment: Finally! Great!

Answer (score 5):

A workaround using `SUBTOTAL`. Create 2 columns A and B. A must always have a value and B has a set of formulas. These 2 columns look like this:

```
A |           B
---------------------------
1 | =NOT(SUBTOTAL(103, A1))
1 | =NOT(SUBTOTAL(103, A2))
1 | =NOT(SUBTOTAL(103, A3))
```

`SUBTOTAL` returns a subtotal using a specified aggregation function. The first argument 103 defines the type of function used for aggregation. The second argument is the range to apply the function to.

- 3 means `COUNTA` and counts the number of values in the range
- +100 means ignore hidden cells in the range.

The result of `SUBTOTAL` with a range of 1 cell will be 0 when the cell is hidden and 1 when the cell is shown. `NOT` inverts it.

Now you can read the column B with your script to know if a row is hidden.

*Here's the transposed question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27846180/1385429*

Answer (score 3):

The issue tracker holds that request [since Aug 3, 2010](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=195) with a Medium priority and just a "Triaged" status. More than 3 years and no signs of solution from the GAS team.

My workaround was to use a special leading character that would indicate the visibility state of the row/column, it is a leading backtick (`) in the cells of top header row/column.
In case if **merged cells** are used in column headers, then **an empty top row should be dedicated** just for that functionality until the google engineers will improve the API.
Same applies if there are **formulas** in the 1st row/column cell(s).
These **dedicated rows/columns** itself can be hidden.

After starting to use this functionality each show/hide column/row command should be performed from a customized menu, otherwise there'll be errors when iterating through the range programmatically, because of the missing/excessive backtick.

e.g. to hide rows of selected cells the following function is invoked

```js
function hideSelectedRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();

  // hide rows and add a ` backtick to the header cell
  for (var row = range.getRow(); row <= range.getLastRow(); row++)
  {
    // add backtick only if it isn't there (that may happen when manually unhiding the rows)
    var cellHeader      = sheet.getRange(row, 1)
    var cellHeaderValue = cellHeader.getValue()    
    if ( !cellHeaderValue.match(/^`/) ) {
      cellHeader.setValue('`' + cellHeaderValue)
    }

    // hide rows of selected range
    sheet.hideRows( row );
  }
}
```

and the menu

```js
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
.addMenu("Show/Hide", [
    { name : "Hide Selected Rows",    functionName : "hideSelectedRows"    },
    { name : "Hide Selected Columns", functionName : "hideSelectedColumns" },
    null,
    { name : "Hide Rows",             functionName : "hideRows"            },
    { name : "Hide Columns",          functionName : "hideColumns"         },
    null,
    { name : "Show Rows",             functionName : "showRows"            },
    { name : "Show Columns",          functionName : "showColumns"         },
    null,
    { name : "Show All Rows",         functionName : "unHideAllRows"       },
    { name : "Show All Columns",      functionName : "unHideAllColumns"    }
  ])
```

Once google engineers find the time to improve the onChange event, it will be possible to put those backticks automatically. Currently the changeType is limited to [EDIT, INSERT_ROW, INSERT_COLUMN, REMOVE_ROW, REMOVE_COLUMN, INSERT_GRID, REMOVE_GRID, OTHER](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events) without any details on which Row/Column was inserted/removed. Looks like the team behind GAS is scanty. I wish they could hire more programmers (khm khm)

Comment: Where is the full script ? I want to try it out

Answer (score 0):

As for workaround, it is possible by using [`SUBTOTAL`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093649) function which can returns a subtotal for a vertical range of cells.

Syntax is:

```
SUBTOTAL(function_code, range1, [range2, ...])
```

where hidden values can be skipped for any of these codes by prepending 10 (to the single-digit codes).

For example 102 for `COUNT` while skipping hidden cells, and `110` for `VAR` while doing so.

Related: [Google Spreadsheets sum only shown rows](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/45677/22759) at Webapps SE