# Google SpreadSheet Scripts: how get filtered DataRange

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm using

```
  sheet.getDataRange()
```

to get all cells. It fetch all rows even hidden (that was filtered).

How can I get only not hidden rows (the rows that user see when he/she opens a spreadsheet)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is already an existing issue on [Integration of Tools/Filter with google apps script](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=524) and, based on that issues tracker, this feature hasn't been added yet.

You may, however, try alternative solutions given in this SO post - [Google Script Filter Or Hide Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707027/google-script-filter-or-hide-row-need-help). One of the solutions given is by reducing a set of data with the use of an array and a `hide` method as shown below.

```
function MasterFilter() {
  var headers = 4; // # rows to skip
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();

  //show all the rows
  sheet.showRows(1, maxRows);

  //get data from column B
  var data = sheet.getRange('B:B').getValues();

  //iterate over all rows
  for(var i=headers; i< data.length; i++){
    if(data[i][0] == false){
      sheet.hideRow(sheet.getRange(i+1,1));
    }
  }
}
```

I hope one of the solutions given works for you. :)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I need something like  `row.isHidden()`. But it is not implemented too.  I've found similar [post on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793805/how-to-skip-hidden-rows-while-iterating-through-google-spreadsheet-w-google-app)